# DRY version of python if statements

Tags: python, django

I am trying to do a database insert, with a table that has about twenty rows. The insert looks like this:

```
if not title.name:
    title.name = data['title']
if not title.synopsis:
    title.synopsis = data['synopsis']
...
```

Basically, I am updating the rows if they don't exist for every db column.

What would be a cleaner, more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for column in ('name', 'synopsis', 'something', 'other'):
    if not getattr(title, column):
        setattr(title, column, data[column])
```

Comment: you should check if hasattr(title,column)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `or`:

```
title.name = title.name or data['title']
title.synopsis = title.synopsis or data['synopsis']
```

or alternatively you can do it dynamically:

```
for attr in data:
    if not getattr(title, attr):
        setattr(title, attr, data[attr])
```

Comment: If `data` is a dictionary, you don't need to use `.keys()`. Iterating over a dictionary iterates over its keys.

Answer (score 1):

Use `getattr` and `setattr` functions:

```
for attribute in ['title', 'synopsis']:
   if not getattr(title, attribute):
       setattr(title, attribute, data[atribute])
```

You can read more about them [here](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html#access).